# NSString To NSSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How Can we Store An group OF NSString Objects to an Single Array.....
starting from index = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:string1, string2, string3, nil];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:string1];
[array addObject:string2];
```

pick one, or improve your question if I've misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
NSArray *myStringArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String", @"Another String", @"Last string", nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *myStringArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: string1, string2, string3, ..., stringn, nil];
```